# How to disable calendar using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces calendar. The calendar is placed on primefaces' datatable.

I need to disable the calendar using jquery.

```
<p:column width="170">
    <p:calendar id="vendorStartDate" value="#{articlePromo.fechaInicio}"
       pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mode="popup" showOn="button">
    </p:calendar>
</p:column>
```

Following didn't disable the calendar:

- `$(#vendorStartDate).attr('disabled','disabled');`
- `document.getElementById("vendorStartDate").disabled = true;`

On viewing the source, I could identify that its actually an input text and a button. The input text gets the id = **vendorStartDate_input**. But the button didn't get an id.

The enabling/disabling of the calendar depends on the value of some other column. So, on `onChange` event of that column I need to disable the calendar component - both the input text & button.

I was able to disable the input text using :

- `document.getElementById("vendorStartDate_input").disabled = true;`

How can I disable the button ?

Thanks,
Shikha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot select the button by id, you need to use a different selector.

The `p:calendar` normally is surrounded by a `<span>` and the button is a sibling of the inputText inside this `<span>` element.

So you could use the following jquery statement:

```js
$('#vendorStartDate_input').siblings('button').attr('disabled', 'true');
```

If you want to get all calendar elements inside the table:

```js
$('[id$="vendorStartDate_input"]').siblings('button').attr('disabled', 'true');
```

This will select all elements with ids ending with `vendorStartDate_input`.